# Reduce step size dynamically in Simulink when using CoolProp

Tags: matlab, exception, simulink

I have a model which calls a library for thermodynamic properties computation (CoolProp) from an S-Function. This library raises an error and suddenly stops the simulation if its inputs are not meaningful, which sometimes happens when Simulink perturbs the states, and especially when a `Step` block is present in the model, *even if its output is floating*! I think this is an attempt to foresee system state changes, and I noticed that reducing the step size reduces the problem, but I can't run a simulation of 20'000 s at 10 us (yes, microseconds!) time steps when it already takes 15 minutes with 5 s step size!

Is there a way to catch that error (raised by a call to `error()`, I suppose) and tell Simulink "Ehy, the step size you're using is too big"?

**EDIT**: I'm using `ode45` solver, but nothing changes even with `ode23tb` or `ode15s`, apart from simulation time which increases dramatically.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using a fixed-step solver, you probably want to look into using a variable-step solver instead, which will adjust the step size dynamically based on what the model is doing. If you have a numerically stiff system (which appears to be the case), you probably want to use `ode15s` or `ode23t`. You can constrain the solver step size to be between a minimum and maximum step size. See [Choosing a solver](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/choosing-a-solver.html) in the documentation for more details

Comment: I'm using a variable step solver (ode45, but with ode23tb or others the problem is still present). However, CoolProp makes the simulation abort when values are not meaningful, whereas I want to tell Simulink reduces the current step size in that case.

Comment: You can't. The solver decides on the step size based on the dynamics of the model, not the user. You can experiment with changing the solver settings (e.g. reducing the minimum step size or changing some of the tolerances), but that's about it. I would also try `ode15s`.

Comment: Like I said, the solver decides on the step size, not the user.